# Magento 2 “website price scope” values available on product grid

Tags: magento, magento2

When viewing the product grid on the backend of Magento 2, how can I have the price scope of site “b” and site “c” as columns for each product as well? The same as the price column... Which would be the site “a” price technically.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: How is that not a programming question? Don’t split hairs with other forums

Comment: The fact that you didn't ask anything about programming made it not-a-programming question. And to bolster that fact the accepted answer also does not have anything to do with programming. This entire question is off-topic. Can you clarify how this is splitting hairs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigate to magento admin->catalogue->products.

Now on product grid page click on **Filters** button in mass actions and select store view from popup generated.

Please refer to the attached screen-shot and set scope,If you want anything else do let me know
[image: For Filter button]
[image: Store scope for grid]

Comment: interesting. this is indeed works to show the price for the other store. The follow up question I have is if both prices would be visible when "All store views" option is selected? obviously not out-of-the box, but perhaps a plugin or module could manage this task?

Comment: Thats not possible in normal ways.As there is no extension to do so.You can only show price for one store at a time.Also you extend mass action block to extend the functionality and add a column for other store